# 22.10: Laptop doesn't charge on suspend

Tags: suspend, laptop, charging

When I close the lid on laptop or if I put the laptop in suspend it doesn't charge.
It does charge if the laptop on or if it is turned off.

I can tell it is truly not charging during suspend because my charger has an Amp meter on it and indicates 0.0amps @ 20V.

Any thoughts? Also any tips on how to debug would be appreciated. I have looked at dmesg and nothing stands out.

EDIT: The Laptop is a NUC 11 P14e. It charges with USB-C

UPDATE: I just updated to the latest BIOS. No change in the behavior.

system info:

```
OS: Ubuntu 22.10 x86_64 
Host: CMCN1CC 
Kernel: 5.19.0-23-generic 
Uptime: 4 hours, 59 mins 
Packages: 1762 (dpkg), 6 (flatpak), 9 (snap) 
Shell: bash 5.2.2 
Resolution: 3000x2000 
DE: GNOME 43.0 
WM: Mutter 
WM Theme: Adwaita 
Theme: Yaru [GTK2/3] 
Icons: Yaru [GTK2/3] 
Terminal: gnome-terminal 
CPU: 11th Gen Intel i7-1185G7 (8) @ 4.800GHz 
GPU: Intel TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] 
Memory: 3932MiB / 15618MiB
```

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include the brand and model of notebook you’re using and whether it charges via USB-C or with a dedicated power port? This will make it easier to offer a correct answer as some machines need to have a USB setting tweaked to ensure charging (and discharging) via USB is enabled during suspend 

Comment: @matigo I edited the post. Thanks! Also what kind of USB settings are you referring to? That sounds helpful, the laptop charges with USB-C.

Comment: A system hibernated or suspended does not use the OS on the system and that makes this a hardware issue. Report the issue to the manufacturer Maybe there is a reason for this. And I would suggest to turn suspend off and let a lid close do nothing but to turn the display off.

Comment: Interesting. It works fine with windows 10 installed. Made me think it was a software/OS issue.